# web service that uses Soap extension called twice at same time

Tags: c#, web-services

I have two web services, *GetStreets* and *GetCities*, that use another web service at the same time called *Location* (don't ask why I do this, I just have to). The problem with this is that these web services are called at pretty much the same time in my .net application.

My question is, how can I either make one of them wait until the writing that happens in Soap Extension for Location is finished before it can write as well or how can I rename the file to where is written so that the two services write to a different file each time.

The GetInitializer method that creates the file name:

```
    public override object GetInitializer(Type WebServiceType)
    {
        string filename = string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}.log", WebServiceType.FullName, methodName, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SoapLogPath"] + "\\" + filename;
    }
```

P.S.: I already use using and lock:

```
    public override void ProcessMessage(SoapMessage message)
    {
        lock (thisLock)
        {
            switch (message.Stage)
            {
                case SoapMessageStage.BeforeSerialize:
                    //WriteOutput(message);
                    break;
                case SoapMessageStage.AfterSerialize:
                    WriteOutput(message);
                    break;
                case SoapMessageStage.BeforeDeserialize:
                    WriteInput(message);
                    break;
                case SoapMessageStage.AfterDeserialize:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The method writes away the input message
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">The soap message that will be logged</param>
    public void WriteOutput(SoapMessage message)
    {
        newStream.Position = 0;
        using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using(StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                string soapString = (message is SoapServerMessage) ? Environment.NewLine + "Output SoapResponse" : "Output SoapRequest";
                w.WriteLine("-----" + soapString + " at " + DateTime.Now);
                Copy(newStream, fs);
                newStream.Position = 0;
                Copy(newStream, oldStream);
            }
        }
        //Force clean up
        GC.Collect();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying the lock was one step, but I also gave read access:
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.ReadWrite))